# Local FileSharing via a Web Interface

Tags: c#, javascript, extjs, download

We have a document management system where users upload documents via a web page and we keep track of the files on our server in the cloud.  Some users would like to store their files on a local file share in their offices as \server\folder\file.doc and instead of uploading the document itself, they would just give us that “URL”.

When viewing that document in our system they would just see a link to that URL, something like:

```
<a href="\\server\folder\file.doc">Your file</a>
```

Unfortunately browsers won’t allow links like that (or file:// links) so I’m trying to find a way to make this work. I have done some research and read a few Web pages where the people tell me that you cannot access a file from the browser with the URL – file://. This is blocked in mostly all the browser because this can cause a huge security threat.

We need this to work in Firefox, Chrome and IE, and I’ve seen some possible way to do this using some add-ons but it seems like a very clumsy way to do this.

These are some of the add-ons I have tried:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/locallink/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/?src=search

Another option is to change some of the settings for Firefox itself to allow some of these features to work but doing that for more than 1000 users is just going to be impractical.

I am assuming I’m not the first person to have this problem.  Has anyone found a reasonable solution that can work across browsers without causing a support nightmare (e.g. having to change settings, or install plugins)?

After much investigation and advice I found on the answers below this is practically impossible unless you want open major security holes in the system.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any sensible way of doing what you're after. You have the FileAPI which you can access via Javascript which should let you read/write files accessible as network paths - the restriction being that the user actually has to 'pick' the file using an open/save file dialog.

So you couldn't just show them a list of files to work with - they'd have to pick it every time.

The best you could do is have a list of files stored on your servers and a 'work with local file' button to use the FileAPI to push data around. Using FileAPI of course also restricts you to modern browsers only (no IE8)

Alternatively you could use a signed java applet (it'd need to be strongly signed to get local file access) which runs in the browser to augment your access to local files and handle it all that way.

The FileAPI reference can be found at http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. use Sencha Desktop to deploy the app as a desktop application
2. use Flash

   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000451.html
3. use a signed Java applet